# Use cython to protect python file, but showing cannot find xlsx file

Tags: cython

Currently what I have are 3 files presenter.py, model.py and view.py; view is the GUI part and presenter.py is the main function which using the parameters.xlsx, both code and spreadsheet we wanted to protect. So I used cython to build a setup.py which showed here:

```
import sys
from os.path import abspath, join, dirname
from distutils.core import setup
from distutils.extension import Extension
#from Cython.Distutils import build_ext
from setuptools import find_packages 
from Cython.Build import cythonize

setup(name = 'presenter', ext_modules = cythonize('presenter.py'), packages = find_packages())
setup(name = 'model', ext_modules = cythonize('model.py'), packages = find_packages())
setup(name = 'view', ext_modules = cythonize('view.py'), packages = find_packages())
```

Then I got view.so, presenter.so and model.so.
At termina, I import the three packages and run the main function under presenter package so no one will have access or source code. However, I got this :

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "view.py", line 801, in view.TernaryStartScreen.done_button_is_pressed
File "presenter.py", line 530, in presenter.init_ternary_view
File "/Users/txzhang1122/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/xlrd/**init**.py", line 111, in open_workbook
with open(filename, "rb") as f:
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'parameters.xlsx'
zsh: abort      python

Which is really weird. I also want to protect the excel sheet, so I only want to give people the .pyd or .so file. Could someone please help me? Because after I send out the .so file I don't want to resend the excel sheet.

Comment: It isn't really weird. Making a compiled module using Cython does __nothing__ to any excel files it tries to load. Why would it?

Comment: Thanks. So how can I also protect my excel sheet if I want to also send that to distribute?

Comment: You could try putting a copy of it into a huge bytes string, wrapping that with `io.BytesIO` and then loading from the `io.BytesIO` rather than the filename. It'd be a pretty weak way of "protecting" it, but then "protecting" a module with Cython is also fairly weak. There's isn't really a great solution for any of this.